# JS - Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css, setattribute

I am pretty new to javascript and want to code a header of an html site. 
JS: when the window width is smaller than 1215px --> left part goes 100% width; right part of the header to 0

I always get the "Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null " Error!

Please Help!
Code:

```js
if (window.innerWidth < 1215) {
    document.getElementById("#headerLeft").setAttribute("style", "width:100%");
    document.getElementById("#headerRight").setAttribute("style", "width:0%");
} else {
    document.getElementById("#headerLeft").setAttribute("style", "width:50%");
    document.getElementById("#headerRight").setAttribute("style", "width:50%");
}
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
}

header{
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
}

#headerLeft {
    background-color:#FF7043;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}

#headerRight {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    height:100px;
    float:right;
}

.headerTitle {
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin:15px;
    font-size:70px;
}

#headerRight .headerTitle {
    text-align:left;
    color:#FF7043;
    font-weight:300;
}

#headerLeft .headerTitle {
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:900;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>example</title>
    
    <!-- css -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <!-- fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,900,100,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
    <!-- javascripts -->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    
</head> 
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="headerLeft">
            <p class="headerTitle">example</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="headerRight">
            <p class="headerTitle">example</p>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <nav>
    </nav>
    
    <main>
    </main>
    
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you may want to take a look at [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is because all of your calls to `document.getElementById` are failing to find anything since there aren't any elements with those IDs.  Looks like jQuery habits in play, remove the `#` from your IDs.

Comment: It looks like it's also running too soon...

Comment: Yep, the script should be included ad _bottom_ of the page, not in the head. Or it should be wrapped in an eventListener for the `window.load` event.

Answer (score 3):

At first do selection by Id without '#'.
The second is to set style in such way:

```
document.getElementById('').style.width = "20%";
```

Comment: this is javascript, the same as $('#myVar')... in jQuery. Or isn't it?

Comment: In terms of searching they are equal because trying to find same tag by `id=myVar` but  `getElementById` is designed to find a tag only by `id` and muc faster. jQuery search by `$()` is closer to `querySelector` which accept any kind of selector as `.className|span|#id_of_the_tag`